# Reference to cast enumeration returns wrong value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Consider the following code:

```
enum TestEnum
{
   TEST_ENUM_5 = 5
};

class Test
{
public:
   Test() { mType = TEST_ENUM_5; mVal = 1; }
   TestEnum& type() { return (TestEnum&)mType; }

private:
   uint16_t mType;
   uint16_t mVal;
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
   Test test;
   assert( test.type() == TEST_ENUM_5 );
}
```

The program compiles fine with MSVC 2010 - no errors or warnings. But the assertion fails - the value returned is not 5 but rather 0x00010005.

In other words the value of the returned enumeration is interpreted as a 4 byte value - including the contents of the following short. I can see why the compiler is doing this, the reference is a ref to the address of mType, and a register is being loaded with the next 4 bytes.

But is this correct behavior for the compiler?

Shouldn't it know that TestEnum& is a reference to a 16-bit quantity? Or if it doesn't want to do that, shouldn't it warn?

That aside, what I'd like to do is store a short enumeration into a 16 bit value, and have method that returns a reference to it, that is typed as that typedef. That is logically what I want is an interface that allows me to:

```
test.type() = TEST_ENUM_5;
```

And have it know at compile time that only values from TestEnum are expected. For that matter I want users of the class when they read it to know TestEnum values are expected here.

Comment: Please copy-paste a **complete** program for this example. This program fails to compile. Also, is the redundant assignment in Test::Test a typo?

Comment: You never assigned to `mType`.

Comment: seth: that was a typo. fixed.

Comment: Please don't close the question because of a typo. The problem is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the enum has to be two bytes, and that the return type of `type()` has to be an enum reference.

C++11 has a feature whereby you can specify the underlying type of an enumeration:

```
enum TestEnum : unsigned short
{
   TEST_ENUM_5 = 5
};

   TestEnum& type() { return mType; }
private:
   TestEnum mType;
```

Comment: Not wonderfully happy to introduce dependency on c++11. But your solution does work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need such usage `test.type() = TEST_ENUM_5;` just implement it correctly:

```
   Test() { mType = TEST_ENUM_5; mVal = 1; }
   TestEnum& type() { return mType; }

private:
   TestEnum mType;
```

**upd:** "2-bytes" version:

```
   Test() { mType = TEST_ENUM_5; mVal = 1; }
   uint16_t& type() { return mType; }

private:
   uint16_t mType;
```

Comment: Or rather it will create a 4 byte enum. I need 2 bytes

Comment: Tried that already: error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'uint16_t' to 'TestEnum &'

Comment: There is no conversions between `uint16_t` and `TestEnum` in my code.

Comment: Err... but then the return type won't be TestEnum.